# Slot scope with multi parameters

Tags: vue.js, slot

When I tried to use two parameters in vue slot scope, I can't find any example about it. When I use the following code to achieve my needs, it will report a parsing error

```html
<template v-slot:name="text, record">
    <div>{{record.name}}</div>
    <div>{{record.short_name}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please post exact error message (as text)

Answer (score 17):

In the parent you should use `v-bind` to pass props.

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Other-Examples
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

  ```
   <slot name="mySlot" v-bind:text="text" v-bind:record="record"/>
   // or
   <slot name="mySlot" v-bind="{ text, record }"/>
  ```

In the child component you can use destructuring.

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props

  ```
   <template v-slot:mySlot="{ text, record }">
     <div>{{ record.name }}</div>
     <div>{{ record.short_name }}</div>
   </template>
  ```

Comment: could you remove the ambiguity of `name="name"`, `record.name`, and `v-slot:name`

Comment: It seems like double-destructuring does not work here, am I correct? e.g. `v-slot:mySlot="{ {short_name} = record }"`